# bootstrap list inline with vertical align icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with bootstrap 3+. i have this code for list inline with icon :

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <h2><a href=""><i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i> test link</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a href=""><i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i> test link</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this worked but icon not in middle vertical align. how do fix this problem ?!

DEMO : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z52bL7L6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.fa {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/z52bL7L6/1/